# copy files to remote server, maintain remote acls

Tags: linux, rsync, access-control-list

Currently I am using rsync to copy files from local machine to remote. local does not have ACLs while remote does have ACLs.

I would like the files that are rsynced across to maintain the ACL's that are already in place, every thing I have tried so far (--no-perms, --acls, --no-acls etc) ends up with files that have no ACLs set.

Is this possible with rsync, or do I need some other app for this job?

All I want is to copy files from A -> B and have all of B's permissions, ACL's and x flags remain as is.

Answer (score 1):

these things are not really nice in linux because posix acls are very limited.

Maybe what you need is to set the default acl mask on the dir, all new files will inherit that

`setfacl -m d:u::rwx,d:g::rwx,d:g:othergroup:rwx,d:m:rwx,d:o:r-x dir`

so what you do is -m modify the d default acl , and you add a 'd' default othergroup with rwx perms for instance.

Or you can use cron or cfengine/puppet/whatever to reset the permissions every few minutes.

If only the [richacl paches](http://www.bestbits.at/richacl/) would be merged ....

Comment: thanks, I will give that a go and see. Might look at the cron also